# PHP Doctrine SoftDelete - Include deleted records?

Tags: php, doctrine, soft-delete

If I have one of my PHP Doctrine objects act as a SoftDelete, is it possible to include deleted items in the results of certain queries?  What I'm looking for is something like this...

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Test t')
    ->where('id < ?', 25)
    *->includeDeleted()*;
```

Something like this would be useful as for most queries I want deleted records excluded, but sometimes (for example, to administrators) I want to be able to include records that have been soft deleted.  Is there some good way to do this with SoftDelete or should I simply add an additional where clause onto most queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory glance at the source [here](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.1/lib/Doctrine/Template/SoftDelete.php) and [here](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/branches/1.1/lib/Doctrine/Template/Listener/SoftDelete.php), this functionality does not seem to provided by the `SoftDelete` behaviour. You have to add a `where` clause manually like you suggest.

(I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure `Doctrine_Query` can not be extended dynamically by way of a behaviour like you can with `Doctrine_Record`. You *could* always write a special `Doctrine_Query` subclass which adds `includeDeleted()`, but that seems like more thouble than it's worth :) )

Answer (score 4):

It returns all records from table (include softDeleted)

```
public function findAllWithDeleted()
{
    $query = $this->createQuery('a');
    $query->addWhere('(a.deleted_at IS NULL OR a.deleted_at IS NOT NULL)');
    return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: life saver!! Cant believe they wrote like billion lines of code without giving this as an option!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you may disable soft-deleteable filter
http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html

// This will disable the SoftDeleteable filter, so entities which were "soft-deleted" will appear in results
$em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');

Answer (score 2):

```
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS, false);
```

After this you can select, update, delete data like softDelete is off.

Answer (score 1):

We had a bug in Doctrine 1.2.2 where ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS was ignored AND the softdelete column had the wrong name. The solution is to overwrite the listener:

```
$m = new MyModel;
$m->setListener(new MockListener());
$m->getTable()->getQueryObject(); //... and so forth
```

with a dummy class:

```
class MockListener implements Doctrine_Overloadable
{
    public function __call($m, $a){}
}
```